# Load php file in symfony 2 directory from jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I have this line of code (jQuery) in a twig file inside a bundle( BundleDir/Bundle/views/mapname/index.html.twig) :

```
$('#datacount').load('getDataCount.php');
```

my question is where do i need to put getDataCount.php file in the symfony 2 directory.
It keeps saying that this file can't be found..

Thanks !

Comment: tipically into the web folder, can you inspect which URL was called?

Comment: User a proper route inside Symfony, not raw php files please!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery.load() performs an HTTP GET request, in your case it's GETting 'getDataCount.php'.

Either you really (really, really) want that file to standalone, and you can just put a "/" and move the file in your web folder

```
$('#datacount').load('/getDataCount.php');

app/..
src/..
web/getDataCount.php
```

or you want it to be a symfony controller, and you must use routes and controllers as defined in the Book http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

Cheers