# Load file in symfony 2 directory from jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony

I'm working with symfony and I have this line of code (jQuery) inside a twig file inside a symfony bundle.

```
    $('#carga-1').load('objectives.html');
```

my question is where do i need to put the file objectives.html in the symfony 2 directory. The firebug keeps saying that this file can't be found..

Before asking, I tried to add a / to the file path and move it into my web folder as this thread suggested:

[Load php file in symfony 2 directory from jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27862265/load-php-file-in-symfony-2-directory-from-jquery) -
But with no effort

I think the problem is I can't find the correct path,
I tried copypastying the file several times in lot of locations to see if I had luck, with no effort.

To be clearer:

(absolute) path to the html.twig file that summons the .js via 'Asset'  - is:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/TP/src/TP/MainBundle/Resources/views/Default/layout.html.twig
```

path to the .js file loaded via 'Asset' - is:

```
TP/web/bundles/TP/js/reveal.js
```

How can I know where should I put the 'objectives.html' file, in order to be loaded THIS way and not with the Symfony way ?   because after this I will load a PHP and I prefer not to convert it to 'twig'

Comment: The correct way in symfony2 would be to create a controller action that serves you this file. Then you would call it like `.load('/controller/action');`

Comment: Using that way the working path was 
    .load('action'); 
and not
    .load('/controller/action');

But what if I wan't to do the other way? is there a method to know where to put it ?

Comment: Then it should be put in the `web/` directory.

Comment: Not again. Putting the file in web/   and calling it as   .load('objectives.html.twig); doesn't do the trick.  Also it doesnt't throw any error, but it don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in `web/some_path` directory, and when you want to reference it in your template do it like this:

```
$(..).load('{{ asset("some_path/objectives.html") }}');
```

---

**Update:** if you can't process the `js` file using twig, you have to pass the value i.e: path to that js file, from your main template. If you're using some external library, then it almost certainly provides a way for you to do that. If you've written the js yourself, you can do something like this:

```
// in your js file
var YourScriptObject = {
  path: '',
  setPath: function(p){
    this.path = p;
  }
  init: function(){
    // do everything that you did before in the js here,
    // but use YourScriptObject.path as your path.
  }
}
```

---

```
// in the main template
// first include the js
// then
$(document).ready(function(){
  YourScriptObject.setPath('{{ asset("some_path/objectives.html") }}');
  YourScriptObject.init();
});
```

Comment: It throws error because I can't use twig variables {{ }}  inside my .js file that has my .load()

Comment: That's alright, make what you pass to `load` dynamic, i.e: a variable, put everything inside the js file in a function, and call it after you set the value for that variable in the main script.see updated answer.